# Le « passe » sanitaire : passeport ou laisser-passer ou autrement etc. ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, terminologie, origine-ou-raison, abréviations

Je [lis](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/2021-07-13/ruee-sur-les-vaccins-en-france-apres-les-annonces-de-macron.php) que le Président Macron a employé le terme « passeport sanitaire » dans une allocution ; sur Lemonde.fr je lis un « passe sanitaire »<sup>1</sup> ; dans une [dépêche](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/2021-07-14/14-juillet-a-paris/avec-le-passeport-sanitaire-c-est-la-fete-mais-il-manque-quelque-chose.php) de l'AFP je lis « le pass ». J'apprends que le [*passe*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passe/2) (n.m) est une abréviation de [*passe-partout*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passe-partout) attestée depuis 1894 (TLFi) et on le trouve [employé](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26538431) aussi dans d'autres domaines.

---

- Y a-t-il une nuance de sens entre le *passe sanitaire* et le
  *passeport sanitaire* ; est-ce un *laisser-passer* ?
- L'emploi de l'abréviation *passe* (n.m.) s'étend-il aussi au
  *passeport* ou autrement dit *passe sanitaire* est-il une abréviation de *passeport sanitaire* ?
- Historiquement *passe* (n.m.) a-t-il déjà signifié *laisse-passer* ?
- Dans le *passe sanitaire*, « passe » constitue-t-il une extension de
  sens de *passe-partout* vers *laisser-passer*, s'agit-il d'un
  emprunt sémantique avec adaptation (ajout du *e*) ou autrement ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Le GDT critique l'emploi « [passe sanitaire](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26559122) » (« Le terme *passe sanitaire* ne s'intègre pas au système linguistique du français d'un point de vue sémantique, le substantif [*passe*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3803) n'ayant pas le sens de « laissez-passer » en français. ») et le DHLF comporte ce qui m'apparaît être une omission du deuxième sens de *passe*, car il ne réfère qu'à 1 (n.f.) puis passe à 3 (n.f) un calque de l'anglais en français du Québec. La BDL laisse entendre que l'emploi au féminin pour *laisser-passer* est vieilli et calqué sur l'anglais. Reste qu'une *passe d'autobus* est usuel pour moi (au Québec).</sub>

Comment: Le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* donne « passe » (n.f.) comme déverbal de passer, avec le sens de permis de circulation. Or le mot, bien que désormais souvent remplacé par « carte » (Passe navigo →Carte navigo en 2014) est désormais  masculin ([wiktionnaire NC 2](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passe#Nom_commun_2)). À mon avis c'est le même sens du mot qui a évolué de fém. en masc. quand ?

Comment: Un passeport (sens premier « pièce délivrée à une personne pour lui permettre de circuler librement ») est un justificatif d'identité délivré  par une administration et qui permet la circulation de personnes. Le laissez-passer peut concerner des personnes ou des choses et n'est pas forcément délivré par une administration.

Comment: — Autre terme employé en Europe : Certificat sanitaire. À voir, cet [article](https://www.vie-publique.fr/en-bref/279133-covid-19-le-certificat-sanitaire-europeen-au-1er-juillet-2021) d'un site gouvernemental qui désigne ce qui semble être un même objet par « certificat sanitaire » « passeport sanitaire » « pass sanitaire ».

Comment: Une petite recherche google actualité nous 37M d'occurence pour *pass sanitaire* contre 28M pour *passe sanitaire*, donc ça semble plutôt être un emprunt (même approximatif) à l'anglais que l’abréviation de passe-partout.

Comment: Personnellement j'aurai plutôt que c'est le "pass-sanitaire" qui est "passeport sanitaire" tout comme on utilise "passeport vaccinale"

Comment: Le [gouvernement](https://www.gouvernement.fr/pass-sanitaire-toutes-les-reponses-a-vos-questions) utilise l'orthographe "pass", sans *e*. Si tu te demandes quelle orthographe est "la bonne" parmi toutes celles citées, c'est sûrement celle-là.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que le certificat Covid numérique UE ?
Intitulé « Certificat Covid numérique UE », **ce pass sanitaire contient une preuve de non contamination au Covid, parmi les 3 suivantes (une de ces 3 preuves suffit) ** https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/actualites/A15022 //Il faut faire des recherches à site:.fr

Comment: Quand _pass sanitaire_ est utilisé sur gouvernement ou service public, c'est presque tout le temps entre guillemets... Par ailleurs n'hésitez pas à répondre.

Answer (score 2):

Un **pass** est le plus souvent compris comme synonyme de laisser-passer, donc le mot est pour moi clairement un anglicisme, mais assez solidement implanté en France, couramment utilisé depuis au moins vingt deux ans et probablement bien plus.

- On trouve des [**Pass** Culture Sport](https://player.ina.fr/player/embed/NA00001286096/1/1b0bd203fbcd702f9bc9b10ac3d0fc21/wide/1) en 1999 à Nantes.
- En 2000, les cinémas Gaumont sortent *[Le **Pass**](https://www.lalibre.be/culture/cinema/2001/04/27/les-visiteurs-en-amerique-mettent-gaumont-en-echec-6DPDJEZLA5GLFMVA6NVVMBMMOU/)*, carte permettant un accès illimité aux cinémas du groupe (puis associés MK2).
- Le *[**Pass** Interrail](https://www.sncf.com/fr/offres-voyageurs/pass-interrail-europe)* (Voyages en train dans toute l'Europe)
- Le *[**Pass** culture](https://pass.culture.fr/)(l)* 2021, [promesse de campagne d'Emmanuel Macron](https://www.franceculture.fr/politique/emmanuel-macron-je-veux-creer-un-pass-culturel-tous-les-jeunes-18-ans-auront-500-euros) en 2017.

La carte Navigo qui a remplacé la carte orange (transports en Île-de-France) a été appelée le ***Passe** Navigo* avant 2014, mais le nom est [encore utilisé](https://www.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/titres-et-tarifs/supports/passe-navigo). La documentation officielle RATP écrit à peu près toujours le mot *passe* avec un *E* mais on trouve quand même chez elle quelques *pass navigo*, un peu plus à la SNCF. La page wikipédia de [Navigo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carte_Navigo) dit que le mot *passe* est une apocope de passe-partout mais sans citer de sources.

1. *Y a-t-il une nuance de sens entre le passe sanitaire et le passeport sanitaire ; est-ce un laisser-passer ?*

Les communications ont souvent insisté sur le fait qu'un pass sanitaire n'est pas un passeport (vaccinal) dans le sens où il laisse la liberté de ne pas se faire vacciner. On peut obtenir un pass sanitaire avec des tests négatifs récents. C'est bien un laisser passer puisqu'il est demandé pour pouvoir accéder à certains lieux.

2. *L'emploi de l'abréviation passe (n.m.) s'étend-il aussi au passeport ou autrement dit passe sanitaire est-il une abréviation de passeport sanitaire ?*

Non. Je n'ai jamais entendu *passe* ou *pass* être utilisés en France comme abréviations de passeport.

3. *Historiquement passe (n.m.) a-t-il déjà signifié laisse-passer ?*

Depuis plus d'une vingtaine d'années, oui, mais plutôt sans *E* final. Avec un *E*, *passe* signifie généralement *passe-partout* mais on peut bien sûr aussi comprendre *passe* comme une normalisation du *pass* anglais.

4. *Dans le passe sanitaire, « passe » constitue-t-il une extension de sens de passe-partout vers laisser-passer, s'agit-il d'un emprunt sémantique avec adaptation (ajout du e) ou autrement ?*

Emprunt sémantique à l'anglais avec ajout optionnel d'un *E*. En France, le mot *pass(e)* est toujours employé au masculin quand il signifie laisser-passer, une carte d'accès aux transports en communs ou à des salles de spectacles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Si l'on se fie au TLF **un** passe est l'abréviation de *passe-partout*, à savoir une clef (en métal ou carte magnétique). Toutes les autres acceptions de *passe* dans le TLF sont féminines.

Dès lors que l'on dit (ou écrit) *un pass* (ou *un passe*) et que le contexte indique qu'il ne s'agit pas d'une clef, il y a néologisme. Et de fait, il reste à déterminer si ce nouveau mot, masculin, s'écrira *pass* ou bien *passe*.

Les éthymologues en sauront sans doute davantage, mais on peut faire confiance aux français pour mettre de l'anglais dans tout, et en particulier dans ce qui est nouveau ; ce qui milite pour *un pass* (Oxford : "an official document or ticket that shows that you have the right to enter or leave a place, to travel on a bus or train, etc.").

Cela peut bien être, pour certains, une abbréviation de *passeport* (avec l'orthographe *pass* ou *passe*), mais en tout cas ce serait une nouvelle abréviation car, de mémoire, on a jamais appelé un passeport (national) *pass(e)*.

De même **le** *pass(e) sanitaire* est aussi un néologisme, puisqu'il est masculin et que ce n'est pas une clef ;^)

Pour résumer, le pass(e) est un néologisme, ce n'est pas une abréviation de *passeport*, et l'avenir nous dira s'il prend un **e** final.

Comment: Un éthymologue, c'est un étymologiste qui a bu ? ;-)